# Prove that ideal generated by.... Is a monomial ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

Similar questions have come up on the last few past exam papers and I don't know how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

> Prove that the ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ generated by $X^2(1+Y^3), Y^3(1-X^2), X^4$ and $ Y^6$ is a monomial ideal.

Comment: How is a monomial ideal defined?

Comment: Do you know of Grobner bases?

Comment: @DanieleA yeah I know Grobner Bases but not sure how to use this to prove this?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the definition I have is' I is a monomial ideal if it has a basis formed of monomials'

Comment: With Grobner bases, you can use the fact that an ideal is monomial if and only if its reduced Grobner basis (w.r.t. any ordering) is monomial. Maybe in this case you can compute a Grobner basis easily

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** $(X^2(1+Y^3), Y^3(1-X^2), X^4, Y^6)=(X^2,Y^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\alpha_1=x^2+x^2y^3, \quad\alpha_2=x^4, \quad \beta_1=y^3-x^2y^3, \quad\beta_2=y^6.$$ Then, $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2)\subset (x^2,y^3)$ is easy. The containment $\supset$ is due to the following expressions: 
$$x^2=\alpha_1-x^2\beta_1-y^3\alpha_2$$ $$y^3=\beta_1+y^3\alpha_1-x^2\beta_2.$$